# ruby get script not working properly when asking for input

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and coding in general.  I am taking the Onemonth ruby course and have hit a road block.

```
print "What's your name? "
name = gets.chomp

print "How old are you? "
age = gets.chomp.to_i
age_in_dog_years = age / 7

puts "Your name is #{name}, and your age in dog years is #{age_in_dog_years}! Woof!"
```

When I run the script in the command prompt and hit enter, the question does not come up.  If I hit enter again, than all of the print area shows up.  I am not sure what I am missing to get the questions to come up when initially running the script.

Thank you.

Comment: This script works as expected. What command are using?

Comment: How do you run the script and what type of shell ?

Comment: I create the script in sublime and run it through gitbash - on a pc.

Comment: The command I use is ruby gets.rb

Comment: what version of ruby are you using?  type `ruby -v` in your command line and past output

Comment: ruby 2.4.3p205 (2017-12-14 revision 61247)

Comment: Could you try running it in Windows' shell and see if the behavior changes? You can do a Windows-R to get the `run` dialog, type `cmd [Enter]`, navigate to the directory containing the Ruby file, and run your `ruby gets.rb`.

Answer (score 0):

I've occasionally had problems with shells or terminals requiring a new line character to flush the buffer and print the text.

I suggest trying `puts` instead of `print`. `puts` appends a new line to your string, while `print` does not.

The appearance would be a little different, as the prompt would take up a line by itself. If you do that, I recommend a blank line separating the first response from the second question.

Comment: I did try this but still had the same result, unfortunately.  I tried just doing the first to lines: puts "What's your name?"
name = gets.chomp    - but I still have the same problem.  I run the script and a blank line shows up, hit enter again, then the question comes up.